# jquery .get() doing nothing

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

what will this code do.

```
var href="localhost/xyz/applications/controllers/login/calllogs/id/49";
var container = $('#paged-data-container');
 $.get(href, { format: 'html' }, function(data){
            //dataContainer.removeClass('loading');
            container.html(data);
        }, 'html');
```

is this code go to calllogs action of login controller and than put the data in container?
if i alert the data it's not alerting what is the problem? and what will this code do?

edited 
   basically there is no problem with href i am getting href like this

```
 $('.pagination-control').find('a').live('click', function(){
    var href = this.href;
    alert(href);
     ....... this is right i guess
```

Comment: Try adding the protocol: `var href="http://localhost/xyz/..."`

Comment: I could imagine that you just got the URL wrong. What happens if you put it like that in the adress bar of the browser? Also check response status code of the request.

Comment: no problem with link sir this was just example  $('.pagination-control').find('a').live('click', function(){
        var href = this.href;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest passing it a valid URL replacing the colon with a semi-colon:

```
var href="http://localhost/xyz/applications/controllers/login/calllogs/id/49";
          ^                                                                  ^
          Add protocol - http://                 Replace colon with semi-colon
```

**Additional Information**: [jQuery `.get()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/).

Comment: basically its calling my calllogs action of my login controller that is the href ??what should i do ??

Answer (score 0):

It will basically try to get the html response from the url you specify and put it inside the container.

There were couple of issues(missing http and colon at the end of url) in your code, try this.

```
var href="http://localhost/xyz/applications/controllers/login/calllogs/id/49";
var container = $('#paged-data-container');
$.get(href, { format: 'html' }, function(data){
        //dataContainer.removeClass('loading');
        container.html(data);
}, 'html');
```

Comment: Yes, `$.get` uses `ajax` itself.

Comment: than y is data not alerting ??i wana see the response

Comment: Did you corrected the errors in your code? Do you see call being made to the server?

Answer (score 0):

try this (without the format map) as that might be the issue.

```
var href="localhost/xyz/applications/controllers/login/calllogs/id/49";
var container = $('#paged-data-container');
$.get(href, function(data) {
    //dataContainer.removeClass('loading');
    container.html(data);
}, 'html');
```